# How to disable Icepdf to call URL for MessageBundle?

Tags: java, applet, resourcebundle, icepdf

I have an question about IcePDF. I'm using it for the applet printing. I found that the IcePDF will try to load the MessageBundle by calling the following URLs which does not exist and 404 results finally.

160.68.1.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:11:22:13 +0800] "GET /ABC/org/icepdf/ri/resources/MessageBundle.class HTTP/1.1" 404 976 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7 6.1) Java/1.7.0_79" 0
160.68.1.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:11:22:13 +0800] "GET /ABC/org/icepdf/ri/resources/MessageBundle_en.class HTTP/1.1" 404 976 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7 6.1) Java/1.7.0_79" 0
160.68.1.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:11:22:13 +0800] "GET /ABC/org/icepdf/ri/resources/MessageBundle_en.properties HTTP/1.1" 404 976 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7 6.1) Java/1.7.0_79" 0
160.68.1.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:11:22:13 +0800] "GET /ABC/org/icepdf/ri/resources/MessageBundle_en.properties HTTP/1.1" 404 976 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7 6.1) Java/1.7.0_79" 0
160.68.1.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:11:22:13 +0800] "GET /ABC/org/icepdf/ri/resources/MessageBundle_en_US.class HTTP/1.1" 404 976 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7 6.1) Java/1.7.0_79" 0
160.68.1.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:11:22:13 +0800] "GET /ABC/org/icepdf/ri/resources/MessageBundle_en_US.properties HTTP/1.1" 404 976 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7 6.1) Java/1.7.0_79" 0
160.68.1.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:11:22:13 +0800] "GET /ABC/org/icepdf/ri/resources/MessageBundle_en_US.properties HTTP/1.1" 404 976

May I know how to disable the applet to call the above Messagebundle?

Answer (score 0):

The message bundles files in question are found in the icerpdf-viewer.jar.  I'm sure why there is "/ABC/" appended to the path of these files.

Could you post a little code that shows the setup of your ICEpdf code?